# Quarto pdf output with text beside figure

Tags: pdf, figure, quarto

I am trying out Quarto and want to place some text next to a figure with pdf output.

I have researched this and it seems there are solutions for HTML output using the bootstrap.css grid system but not for pdf. Some online comments say that bootstrap is natively available in Quarto (not specifying anything about the type of output) - I was skeptical but nevertheless I added *page-layout: custom* to my header and tried the suggested fix ...

[image]

but that just renders as ...

[image]

My header is ..

[image]

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well - after lots of research I have found that I can use div to achieve the desired result ... optionally adjusting the width of each column using {layout}. So this code ...

[image]

Renders nicely as ...

[image]